# While retrieving the current location and set on map is not working properly in Ionic3, Angular4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

While retrieving the current location and set on map is not working properly in Ionic3, Angular4. While we pass latlong of location it works but when we fetch location with plugin of geolocation of Ionic3 then latlong print on console but not set on Google Map.

For **Getting** the current Location in ionic3

```
this.geoLocation.getCurrentPosition().then(pos => {
l_object.latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
l_object.longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
let timeS: Date = new Date(pos.timestamp);
let hours = timeS.getHours(),
  minutes = timeS.getMinutes(),
  seconds = timeS.getSeconds(),
  months = timeS.getMonth() + 1,
  day = timeS.getDate(),
  year = timeS.getFullYear() % 100;
let l_dateTime = this.pad(months) + "-" +
  this.pad(day) + "-" +
  this.pad(year) + " " +
  this.pad(hours) + ":" +
  this.pad(minutes) + ":" +
  this.pad(seconds);
l_object.timestamp = l_dateTime.toString();
resolve(l_object);
}, err => {
resolve(l_object);
});
})
}
```

For **Setting** the current Location in Map

```
for (var i = 0; i < all_latlng1.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(all_latlng1[i][0], all_latlng1[i][1]),
    map: this.map,
    label: all_latlng1[i][1] + "~" + all_latlng1[i][0]
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', ((marker, i) => {
    return () => {
      infowindow.setContent(all_latlng1[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}


this.addUpdateEntryServices.getLatLongTimestamp().then(object => {
  var data: any = object;
  // console.log(data);
  let latlng: any = [];
  latlng[0] = data.latitude;
  latlng[1] = data.longitude;
  all_latlng1.push(latlng);
  console.log(all_latlng1);
}, err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: google maps runs outside angular zone, you could try with `NgZone`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set Latitude, Longitude and Location which comes from plugin then you have to put all variables inside Promise(Resolve, Reject) block and then draw the Map inside Promise Block. If you write map generation code outside the promise block then map is generated without latlong bcz plugin required some time to fetch location details, so we have to put Map Generation code inside Promise.